# Access AWS ALB via HTTPS from localhost

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, localhost, amazon-elb

I have an AWS setup with ECS and ALB. The ALB has https listener which I am trying to configure the SSL Certificate for and forward the traffic to my ECS task.

My problem here is that in development environment we run the application using `localhost`, and when trying to send data to the ALB and ECS task, traffic gets rejected, because I cant add localhost as my domain is the SSL.

Is there any way I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in Route53 and the record sets. I created a new subdomain in Route53 `services.example.com`, with `A Record Type` and Alias targeting the ALB. Then used this subdomain in frontend.

There is no need to add anything to hosts file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can add your domain name in your [hosts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)) file.

```
127.0.0.1 dev.example.com
```

That way, when you request dev.example.com, it will go to your localhost.
Your local application can then talk to the ALB and your browser will see it with the right SSL certificate.

Comment: I added dev.example.com and the ssl has *.example.com, but I still get `net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` in Chrome.

Comment: You should not have localhost in the certificate common name but only `*.example.com` and you should access `dev.example.com` on you computer even if it redirects to your localhost which then call the ALB

Comment: Followed the same procedure, but get the same error in browser! Does port has anything to do with it? Because it is `dev.example.com:3000` in the browser

Comment: Does the ALB have SSL enabled on port 3000?

Comment: ?? The request is sent from localhost:3000 to port 443 of ALB listener. i.e
`dev.example.com:3000 --> ALB-DNS:443`

Comment: Also tried running `dev.example.com` over https, but still no luck.